# Where are the compile options documented with the actual switches?

Tags: compile-vim

If I look in the documentation for Vim, [it lists the compilable features](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+feature-list), but: this list shows the feature as the help output, not how the feature is actually configured during the build. For example, it lists:

```
+cscope
```

but to actually compile this feature, you use a different switch:

```
--enable-cscope
```

How can I get documentation on the actual switches?

Answer (score 1):

To configure the build the script `configure` in the root of the source tree is used.
This script supports the option `--help`. It will print the available options with explanation.

So: `cd` to the root of the source tree and run:

```
$ ./configure --help
`configure' configures this package to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: auto/configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

...
  --enable-cscope         Include cscope interface.
  --enable-workshop       Include Sun Visual Workshop support.
  --disable-netbeans      Disable NetBeans integration support.
  --disable-channel       Disable process communication support.
  --enable-terminal       Enable terminal emulation support.
...
```

Note: Output is about 150 lines.